# Iteration (loop) performance in PHP

Tags: php, performance, loops

how does the performance of a FOR loop compare to that of a FOREACH / WHILE / DO WHILE itation construct in PHP?

Comment: It depends more on the iteration itself then the language constructs used. Use the language construct that expresses best for an iteration in question, but you normally never need to care about performance for the expression itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if there is any kind of difference, that difference will be so small it won't matter at all.

If you have, say, one query to the database, it'll take so long compared to the loop iterating over the results that the eternal debate of for vs foreach vs while vs do will not change a thing -- at least if you have a reasonable amount of data.

So, use :

- whatever you like
- whatever fits your programming standard
- whatever is best suited for your code/application

There will be plenty of other things you could/should optimize before thinking about that kind of micro-optimization.

And if you really want some numbers (even if it's just for fun), you can make some benchmark and see the results in practice.

Answer (score 0):

It's not what you should be aware of. Optimize your algorithms, not the basic language constructions.

Unless you're doing hundreds of millions of iteration in your single script run - it doesn't matter which one you use.

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @cleong: my mission here is to teach people how to do things in a right way, not blindly answer on whatever they ask. In this case - it is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some peoples tried to bench those : http://juliusbeckmann.de/blog/php-foreach-vs-while-vs-for-the-loop-battle.html

> 0.344 seconds - foreach()
>
> 0.506 seconds - while()
>
> 0.530 seconds - for()

In his case, Foreach seems to win.